# Including C# ConsoleApplication in UWA

Tags: c#, console-application, uwp

Does anybody of you guys have experiences with including a C#-based Console Application in a C#-based Universal Windows App?

The reason why I'm asking: I've an already exsisting Console Application developed by another developer. This Application includes a database with all the queries which I need for my App.

The problem: When I try to include the CA in my UWA project many commands like

- private global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef
- throw new global::System.ApplicationException

don't get identified by VS2015.

Is there a way to let the UWA project identify CA commands? For example with adding an external CA-library or something like that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine full .NET (console, winforms, WPF) assemblies with an UWP app, as they're different .NET frameworks. For more details, please read [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477450/using-wpf-dlls-in-uwp-app/34479037#34479037). Part of the code is shareable in a Portable Class Library (PCL), but most likely not all of the code you've written.

Possible solutions:

1. Create an API (yourself or with the other developer) to expose the functionality needed over a (preferably) REST api.
2. Find a way to cheat the system. Example: launch a file (associated to the console application) with the [Launcher api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563559/how-to-start-a-process-from-a-win-8-app) and output the results to a text file on disk, which you then read from your UWP app.

The first one is guaranteed to work. You might find a way to cheat the system for the second 'solution', but there's no guarantee that it won't break in the future when Windows 10 gets updated (experienced that myself for another 'hack' on the upgrade between Windows 8 and 8.1).

Comment: Thanks Bart! I'll check out your solutions!