# Add WEB API within a UWP project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, uwp

I have created a web api (4.5.2) to access sql server table details using ado.net model and controller. And then created a uwp blank project to access that api. It is working. But my doubt is , how can I implement that web api project inside the uwp project? Can I add it as a refernce.

Now I can connect to the web api only when that API project is running.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{ 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:xxxxx/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("Api/GetNames");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var namelist = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*There's no way to put a .NET 4.5.2 Web API project in an UWP app. See [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477450/using-wpf-dlls-in-uwp-app/34479037#34479037) for the difference between .NET and .NETCore.*

Think twice about what you're trying to achieve before merging both projects. You clearly want the API project to be running to be able to test your UWP application, but what is your future target?

- The api should be running on a server (cloud/on premise) and the app should connect to it.

For this scenario it's best to keep both separated. However you can define multiple startup projects in your solution, so you can keep debugging without forgetting to start the API. Right-click the solution => *Set Startup Projects* (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx).

- The database will always be on the same machine as the UWP app.

Do you need the API for something else than the app? Then you can set up a [local IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1zz9df4.aspx) or look at [self-hosted api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api). Or you can use the multiple startup project approach from above.

You only use the API to access the database from your UWP app, because you "there is no other way"? Good news, since the Fall Creators Update (SDK 16299), UWP supports .NET Standard 2.0. This brings SqlClient to UWP, so you can query your database directly from your UWP app. There are plenty of [samples](https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2017/09/02/using-sqlclient-in-uwp/) and [videos](https://stefanwick.com/category/uwp-features-samples/) online for using SqlClient.

Comment: thanks  alot for the information.Can we create local sql server db inside the app?not sqlite.

Comment: SQL Server itself can't run in the app, but you can connect to it (using .netstandard 2.0). I advise you to watch the Ignite video linked and read the blog post. It's very similar to accessing SQL Server from WebApi or a Winforms/WPF application.